# How to put a search result to a form?

Tags: forms, search

I have on my site a simple search that looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" action='<?=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>' class="form" id="form" name="form">
  <input type="text" id="searchfield" name="searchfield" size="35" onkeyup="Search(this.value, 'showdiv', 'wait');">
</form>

<div id="showdiv"></div>
```

The javascript it calls look like this:

```js
function Search(Searchword, sideElement, kaldMessage) {
     document.getElementById(sideElement).innerHTML = kaldMessage;
     try {
     req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* f.eks. Firefox */
     } catch(e) {
       try {
       req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  /* IE-versioner */
       } catch (e) {
         try {
         req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  /* IE-versioner */
         } catch (e) {
          req = false;
         } 
       } 
     }
     req.onreadystatechange = function() {SvarSearch(sideElement);};
     req.open("GET","SearchResult.php" + "?searchword=" + Searchword,true);
     req.send(null);
  }

function SvarSearch(sideElement) {
   var output = '';
   if(req.readyState == 4) {
      if(req.status == 200) {
         output = req.responseText;
         document.getElementById(sideElement).innerHTML = output;
         }
      }
  }
```

It opens a php looking in the database for the searchword a shows echo a link for the person I look for... Very simply :)

But now I have to make a site where I can input the person I click on to a database.
So I have an input field in a form, and if I type "Jo" in the input field it shows ex all the persons names Jones etc, and when I click on one of the names i needs to put that name and id in the input form so I can submit the form and put that name and id in a database. Am I making sense :)

So if I have a database with names and one with jobs, I need a form with two input fields, one where I can search the name and one where I can search the job, and the submit the form, so I can link the two choices in a database...
All the PHP MySql work I know what to do... It's only the javascript part I can't figure out.

Hope someone can help me with a simply solution since Javascript is not my strongest site :)

Michael